# Batch - For Loop 1-100, mod 5 for each

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, modulus

Batch for a class...Can't figure this out. Currently have

```
:forLoop
echo.
for /L %%x in (1, 1, 100) do ( 
    SET /A result=%%x %% 2
    echo %%x
)
```

Any ideas guys?

Edit: I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate from 1 to 100. Then in the for loop obtain modulus of 1,2,3,4, etc. So in my example it would be modulus x. Where x is constantly incrementing.

Comment: Can't figure out what? Your problem statement is not clear, so we don't know what you're having trouble with and what you can't figure out.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate from 1 to 100. Then in the for loop obtain modulus of 1,2,3,4, etc. So in my example it would be modulus x. Where x is constantly incrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:forLoop
echo.
for /L %%x in (1, 1, 100) do ( 
    SET /A result=%%x %% 2
    echo !result!
)
```

The first command is necessary for the variables to be expanded at execution time.

Delayed expansion (at run-time) of the variable is performed with the `!` symbol.

If you use the `%`, you get the parse-time value.

**EDIT:**

Considering Stephan suggestion, i see that we can use `call` for a shorter solution:

```
for /L %%x in (1, 1, 100) do (
    set /A result="%%x %% 2"
    call echo %%result%%
)
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thank you. Any way I can do it without SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and have just a simple for-loop?

Comment: @Rib I think you cant. Block statements are surrounded by parenthesis, and inside this blocks any `%variable%` will replaced by its value at parse-time, this is before the block is executed. You need the run-time value that is constantly changing, then you need to access its value as `!variable!`, and for this is necessary the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` command that let the parser to recognize the `!`. BTW, you can accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: @JosEdu: not quite correct. You can use `for /L %%x in (1,1,100) do call :doit %%x` and then in a "subroutine" use `:doit` - `set /a result=%1 %%2` - `echo %result%`- `goto :eof`. This way, delayed expansion is not needed. However I don't know, if this fits into "have just a simple for-loop"

Comment: This worked with the call. I just realized I need to obtain the average of the modulus. would I use 
    call set /A temp=%%results%%+temp ?

Comment: @Rib I think is better to learn about the delayed expansion, it would be more useful as you try to do more complex things.

Comment: Also, delayed expansion is much faster than using CALL with doubled percents. The difference is striking if there are many iterations.